# How to keep reading logs when executing Ant task?

Tags: java, logging, ant

I have this following code for executing Ant task from Java:

```
public class AntExecutor {
    /**
     * To execute a target specified in the Ant build.xml file
     *
     * @param buildXmlFileFullPath
     * @param target
     */
    public static boolean executeAntTask(String buildXmlFileFullPath, String target, Map<String, String> propertiesMap) {
        boolean success = false;
        DefaultLogger consoleLogger = getConsoleLogger();

        // Prepare Ant project
        Project project = new Project();
        File buildFile = new File(buildXmlFileFullPath);
        project.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());

        if(propertiesMap != null && !propertiesMap.isEmpty()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet : propertiesMap.entrySet()) {
                project.setProperty(entrySet.getKey(), entrySet.getValue());
            }
        }

        project.addBuildListener(consoleLogger);

        // Capture event for Ant script build start / stop / failure
        try {
            project.fireBuildStarted();
            project.init();
            ProjectHelper projectHelper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
            project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", projectHelper);
            projectHelper.parse(project, buildFile);

            // If no target specified then default target will be executed.
            String targetToExecute = (target != null && target.trim().length() > 0) ? target.trim() : project.getDefaultTarget();
            project.executeTarget(targetToExecute);
            project.fireBuildFinished(null);
            success = true;
        } catch (BuildException buildException) {
            project.fireBuildFinished(buildException);
            throw new RuntimeException("!!! Unable to restart the IEHS App !!!", buildException);
        }

        return success;
    }

    /**
     * Logger to log output generated while executing ant script in console
     *
     * @return
     */
    private static DefaultLogger getConsoleLogger() {
        DefaultLogger consoleLogger = new DefaultLogger();
        consoleLogger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
        consoleLogger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
        consoleLogger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);

        return consoleLogger;
    }

}
```

And calling this from some method as :

```
AntExecutor.executeAntTask(buildFile.getPath(), "target name", propertiesMap);
```

The above task starts showing the output logs from Ant in `console`. How to read the console logs which gets printed in console, or save the output logs which is printed as part of `ant` task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `getConsoleLogger`, I used `BuildListener` like this:

```
    List<String> consoleLogs = new ArrayList<>();
    project.addBuildListener(new BuildListener() {
        @Override
        public void buildStarted(BuildEvent buildEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void buildFinished(BuildEvent buildEvent) {
            if(buildEvent.getException()  != null && StringUtils.hasText(buildEvent.getException().getMessage())){
                consoleLogs.add(buildEvent.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void targetStarted(BuildEvent buildEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void targetFinished(BuildEvent buildEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void taskStarted(BuildEvent buildEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void taskFinished(BuildEvent buildEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void messageLogged(BuildEvent buildEvent) {
            if(StringUtils.hasText(buildEvent.getMessage())) {
                consoleLogs.add(buildEvent.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

After which the method returns the `consoleLogs`.